# How to move the scrollbar by touching on it and draging it on touch screens using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to move the scrollbar by touching on it and draging it on touch screens (in nest hub). Here is part my code: I have a table and the table container has got a scroll bar-

```
<div id="table-container" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%" id="myTable">
              
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if ( isTouchDevice() ) {
        document.querySelector("#table-container::-webkit-scrollbar").ontouchmove = function() {
            // some code
        }
}
```

This is my website `https://product.thob.studio/`. I inspect the website and select `nest hub` and then I click `see more` under `shirt` and then a modal appears and the scrollbar appears on the right side of the modal. But I am not able to drag the scroll bar vertically. This is my problem.

Comment: It's notable, that currently tapping the pop-up shows the scrollbar, but dragging the scrollbar triggers an error: `scrollSlider is not defined`. That means there's more code behind the action, you should show all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I have removed that error. please check now.

Comment: But you haven't added the code into the question itself. SO is not a debugging service where you could just throw a link to your codebase, and expect it to be corrected. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it